How to prove this inequality involving operation?
Let $x_i \geq 0$, $i=1, \cdots, n$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq 1$. $0\leq p_i \leq 1$, $i=0, \cdots, n$. $p_n-p_{n-1}>\cdots>p_1-p_0>0$.
If $x_i<1$, $i=1, \cdots, n$, let
\begin{equation*}
M_i=\frac{\left(1-x_i\right)^2}{\left(1-x_i\right)\left( p_n-p_{i-1}\right)-\sum_{k=i+1}^n x_k\left(p_{n+i-k}-p_{i-1}\right).}
\end{equation*} If $x_i=1$, let $M_i=0$.
Simulation suggests if $x_k>0$, then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} M_i\left(x_1, \cdots, x_k, \cdots, x_n\right)>\sum_{i=1}^{k} M_i\left(x_1+x_k, \cdots, 0, \cdots, x_n\right)
\end{equation*} where $2 \leq k \leq n-1$. (Further simulation suggests this may be true only for $k=2$) Note that changing from $\left(x_1, \cdots, x_k, \cdots, x_n\right)$ to $\left(x_1+x_k, \cdots, 0, \cdots, x_n\right)$ makes $M_1, \cdots, M_{k-1}$ decrease but $M_k$ increase. One may thus try to prove a stronger proposition by deleting some terms in $M_1, \cdots, M_{k-1}$ on both sides. But the simulation suggests the inequality may not hold without these terms. In other words, the inequality must be proved as a whole. Reduction both sides to a common denominator is the only way I have in mind, but the algebra looks freaky.
Edit: the context is as follows. I tried to minimize
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i\left(x_1, \cdots, x_k, \cdots, x_n\right).
\end{equation*} Simulation suggests the minimizer satisfies $x_j=0, j=2, \cdots, n-1$. To prove that, it's sufficient to prove
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i\left(x_1, \cdots, x_k, \cdots, x_n\right)>\sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i\left(x_1+x_k, \cdots, 0, \cdots, x_n\right).
\end{equation*} Note that the terms of $k+1, \cdots, n$ are the same on both sides, so the upper bound of the summation can be changed to $k$, which is the inequality I proposed.

So looks the question. Is there any context? $M_i$ depends only on $x_i,\dots x_n$ which suggests a better notation and begs the question what that $M_i(\color{red}{x_1+x_k},\dots,0,\dots x_n)$ means. Suggestion: clean this up and see if the strict inequality holds on a term-by-term basis which implies it for the sum.

@KurtG. It does not hold term by term. Actually, my last paragraph indicates that the inequality holds for i=1...k-1 but not k. One has to add i=1...k-1 up to offset the effect of k.

@KurtG.I also added the context.
